# Disable F1 (Help Button)

Tags: excel, vba

- I'm usually use the F2 button to editing the contents of a cell. Now I'm trying to disable the F1 button in VBA/Excel or just a shortcut key to turn off help dialog box quickly after missclicking it, but the code is off after I restart the excel file:
- I using macro to create a shortcut key:
  IS THERE ANYONE KNOW HOW TO TURN IT (F1 button) OFF FOREVER IN EXCEL FILES ?

```
 Sub DiableHelp()
    '
    ' DiableHelp Macro
    '
    ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+H
    '
    Application.OnKey "{F1}", ""
```

`End Sub`

Comment: Have a look [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/7i4un8/how_to_disable_f1_help_hotkey_permanently/), especially at the "disabling for workbooks you create"-part of the thread. I doubt you'll be able to permanently disable F1 as the help-shortcut in all Excel-files, as this F1-shortcut is used across all Office-packages. If you're running Windows you could disable it in the registry [se here for Win10 example](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/disable-f1-how-to-get-help-in-windows-10/b4ec01ad-eed3-4246-87d7-01c05e16ca71)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Answer work for me in this problem is: Use a shortcut key to close "Help" dialogbox: Ctrl + Space + C

//Only work when does not press outside the dialogbox
Link: https://marqueegroup.ca/resource/keyboard-shortcut-creating-the-power-of-alt-f4/

VBA:

Through the comment from @Prebsus. I found.
https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/7i4un8/how_to_disable_f1_help_hotkey_permanently/
Step 1: Enable Personal.xslb
Step 2: Then apply VBA for Personal.xslb on Excel.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.OnKey "{F1}", ""
End Sub
```

Step 3: Hide it after apply the code
For details to open Personal.xslb: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2020/03/04/excel-personal-macro-workbook/

Or you can change Win 10 configuration: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/disable-f1-how-to-get-help-in-windows-10/b4ec01ad-eed3-4246-87d7-01c05e16ca71?auth=1

Answer (score 3):

I finally figured out the code that disables the F1 key across all platforms, all software, and all applications, WITHOUT changing the registry:

1. Take a small strip of paper. Fold it up a couple times until it is thick enough to jam the F1 key but not so thick as to break the key.
2. Jam the folded paper under or into the sides of the F1 key.
3. Secure with tape if needed.

If that code doesn't work, here's an alternative snippet that can be used:

1. Use bits of plastic or cardboard to make a tiny box that fits around your F1 key.
2. Affix this box with duct tape, so that the F1 key is guarded.

Fool-proof, works on any key, and can easily be reversed if needed!

Answer (score 0):

I use [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com) scripts for various things already, so I just added this one to handle F1 in Excel:

```
; Stop F1 loading help in Excel when I really wanted F2!
; $ uses keyhook (i.e. actual keyboard input) to avoid retriggering this hotkey
$F1::
if WinActive("ahk_class XLMAIN")
{
    MsgBox, You didn't really want F1, did you?
} else {
    Send {F1}
}
Return
```

Of course you could just do nothing rather than displaying a message box if you prefer.